# How to fit data with a cosine function and increasing oscillations in Python?

Tags: python, data-analysis, curve-fitting, data-fitting

I tried to fit the data in the picture:

[image]

with this function:

```
def expcos(x, i0, a, w1, ph, off):
      return i0 + (1-i0)*np.exp(-x/w1) + a*np.cos((2*np.pi/w1)*(x - ph)) + off
```

and curve_fit: `popt, pcov = curve_fit(expcos, x, y, guess)`

But the fitting curve (orange line) is not fitting so well the data after x=0.8

What do you suggest to improve the fitting?

```
x = [1.19995117, 1.14990234, 1.10009766, 1.05004883, 1.        ,
       0.94995117, 0.89990234, 0.85009766, 0.80004883, 0.75      ,
       0.69995117, 0.64990234, 0.60009766, 0.55004883, 0.5       ,
       0.44995117, 0.39990234, 0.35009766, 0.30004883, 0.25      ,
       0.19995117, 0.14990234, 0.10009766]
y = [-4.48635472, -7.46744701, -1.64572445,  0.066374  , -2.38919002,
       -7.16421132, -0.96261029, -4.50088441, -1.74462464, -4.26446956,
       -3.38185233, -1.80706345, -1.14412059, -2.64494386, -1.37471773,
       -1.53031754, -2.00849513, -0.48058228, -0.16275403, -0.10673643,
       -1.06832094, -0.13781298,  0.91363212]
```

Comment: Could you post the errors vector and the initial guess as well? How do you know there is a single frequency ? Is there a signal with higher time resolution ?

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR

You probably will not be able to fit your data to the current model because the oscillation amplitude is fixed to `a` therefore there is no way to make it smaller or bigger (and get more fitness) when signal varies as it happens in your dataset. That is, in your model amplitude is constant so it will not capture amplitude variation.

### Hints

I leave here additional hints when dealing with such non linear problems:

- You have two parameters `i0` and `off` working against each other, that makes the problem harder to the solver while bringing no extra information. Just remove the extra parameters and make the split by hand afterward if you need to;

```
def expcos(x, i0, a, w1, ph):
    return i0 + (1-i0)*np.exp(-x/w1) + a*np.cos((2*np.pi/w1)*(x - ph))
```

- NLLS are powerful but they generally get confused with trigonometric functions as they shape infinitely many local minima on the Error Landscape (the error surface wrt. parameters you are trying to minimize when calling `curve_fit`). At last resort you will need to have a precise and lucky educated guess, but without inspecting the the Error function you will have no guarantee you have found the global optima.
- 23 points for 4 regression parameters is generally not enough to get a clean fit, you may want to get more points in order to capture the complete model dynamic;
- You have strong non linear coupling in addition of trigonometric function: `w1` is implied in two distinct functions and coupled with `ph`. You can at least reduce coupling, without loss of generality, by changing for:

```
def expcos(x, i0, a, w1, ph):
    return i0 + (1-i0)*np.exp(-x/w1) + a*np.cos((2*np.pi/w1)*x - ph)
```

- You need to update the model to adapt amplitude of the trigonometric function in order to capture its amplitude variation. The following model has 6 parameters and still is coupled, but at least it allows amplitude to vary:

```
def model(x, a, b, c, d, e, f):
    return a*x + b + c*np.exp(d*x)*np.cos(2*np.pi*e*x + f)
```